# Adding widgets to Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt-designer

I have recently discovered that Qt supports custom widgets, and that there are sites that provide this kind of widgets ( like [Qt-Apps](http://qt-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=4298) ). If it is relevant, I am interested in getting [this](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Value+Browser?content=50717) widget.

I have downloaded the source code for it, I have extracted it etc. I haven't tried to build it yet, but what I am interested in is having that widget in the widget list in the left side of the Qt Designer so that I can use it my applications.

I either  don't know how to search what I am looking for, or it doesn't exist at all. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

A. Use [promotion](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

The simplest way. This method direct take the source without building it.

B. [Build a plugin lib for Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesignercustomwidgetinterface.html#details)

It's a little bit tedious...

---

To make it short, supposed you have a desired class(widget): `CustomWidget` with `customwidget.cpp` and `customwidget.h`.

1. Create a new factory class, maybe call it `CustomWidgetPlugin` and public inherit `QObject` and `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface` and reimplement some virtual functions.

example:

`customwidget.h`
:

```
    #include <QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>
    #include "customwidget.h"

    class CustomWidgetPlugin : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface) // note this line, it tell moc that the second base class is a plugin interface.

    public:
        CustomWidget(QObject *parent = 0);
        QString name() const;
        QString includeFile() const;
        QString group() const;
        QIcon icon() const;
        QString toolTip() const;
        QString whatsThis() const;
        bool isContainer() const;
        QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent);
    };
```

`customwidget.cpp`
:

constructor:

```
CustomWidget::CustomWidgetPlugin(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
}
```

name getter:

```
QString CustomWidgetPlugin::name() const
{
    return "CustomWidget";
}
```

headerfile getter:

```
QString CustomWidgetPlugin::includeFile() const
{
    return "customwidget.h";
}
```

group name getter:

```
QString CustomWidgetPlugin::group() const
{
    return tr("New Group");
}
```

(the group name define where the widget belongs, and it creates a new group if the name doesn't fit any default group)

[image]

icon (for the displayed icon in designer):

```
QIcon CustomWidgetPlugin::icon() const
{
    return QIcon(":/images/icon.png");
}
```

tool tip for the widget:

```
QString  CustomWidgetPlugin::toolTip() const
{
    return tr("This is a widget, got it?");
}
```

information of *what is this*:

```
QString CustomWidgetPlugin::whatsThis() const
{
    return tr("A widget, already said.");
}
```

define if it is a "container" (can hold another widget or not):

```
bool CustomWidgetPlugin::isContainer() const
{
    return false;
}
```

The factory memeber function:

```
QWidget *CustomWidgetPlugin::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    return new CustomWidget(parent);
}
```

## IMPORTANT!!

At the end of `customwidget.cpp` file, add this macro:

```
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(customwidgetplugin , CustomWidgetPlugin) // (the widget name, the class name)
```

It makes the plugin available the Qt deisgner.

Finally, in your `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += designer plugin release
HEADERS = ../customwidget.h \
customwidgetplugin.h
SOURCES = ../customwidget.cpp \
customwidgetplugin.cpp
RESOURCES = customwidget.qrc
DESTDIR = $(QTDIR)/plugins/designer #assume QTDIR environment variable is set to the directory where Qt is installed.
```

After building this project, next time as you open Qt designer, you will see the widget.

Ref: *C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4*

Comment: So what you mean is that I have to take out the source of that widget I downloaded? Don't I have to build it?

Comment: It's a standard way of creating a widget plugin. If your source has already done this for you,  build it to `$(QTDIR)/plugins/designer`. If not, follow the procedure to build your own.

Comment: @Victor I've check the source that you provided. It's just a form of lib. You can build it as lib and still can use it without designer. But if you'd like to play some drag and drop of the widget in designer, there are works to be done. Besides, if you are looking for a simpler way, check [Promotion](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)

Comment: is there any way to contact you privately?

Comment: I don't know how to create one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51373/discussion-between-victor-and-tay2510)